# How to perform general processing on spark StructType in Scala UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with following schema

```
root
 |-- name: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- address: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- cases: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- caseOpenTime: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- caseDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- caseSymptons: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- duration: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to write UDF that can take "cases" column in data frame and produce another column "derivedColumn1" from this.

I want to write this derivation logic with general processing without using SQL constructs supported by Spark Dataframe. So steps will be:

```
val deriveDerivedColumen1_with_MapType = udf(_ => MapType = (casesColumn: ArrayType) => {
    val derivedMapSchema = DataTypes.createMapType(StringType, LongType)
 
    1. Convert casesColumn to scala object-X
    2. ScalaMap<String, Long> scalaMap = myScalaObjectProcessing(object-X)
    3. (return) scalaMap.convertToSparkMapType(schema = derivedMapSchema)
})
```

For specific use-cases, Dataframe SQL constructs can be used. But I am looking for **general processing that is not constrained by SQL constructs** so specifically looking for ways for:

1. ***How to convert complex spark StructType in Scala datatype Object-X ?***
2. Then perform "SOME" general purpose processing on Scala Object-X
3. ***How to convert back Scala Object-X into spark MapType which can be added as new column in dataframe ?***

Comment: can you show expected final output printschema ??

Comment: It can be anything as I am looking for conversions between Scala type and spark type .I am looking for general processing and not for specific use case.
So for example one of possible outputSchemas could be "someOutput: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string | | | |--value: int"

Comment: converting row to case is challenging specifically if that row has complex datatypes. I would suggest, rather than converting the row to case class  inside udf, put an outer case class and convert the dataset<Row> -> dataset<case> and then call the udf on the sub case class

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I did not get that ... can you please elaborate more  with some example?